# Magento 2 - Cronjob Deadlock issue

Tags: magento2, cronjobs, deadlock

I am facing an interesting issue. I have some custom cronjobs. If I run them manually with `magerun2` (n98-magerun), they will be executed with success. If I let Magento to schedule it and execute it, sometimes the cronjob will NOT run. For example, using a tool like Amasty cron tasks, I see that the cronjob is `pending`. After 2 hours I refresh the page and I don't see any information related to my cronjob (neither in the `cron_schedule` table or in the `var/log/cron.log`).

Checking out also the `magento.cron.log` , I saw the following:

```
SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to   
  get lock; try restarting transaction, query was: DELETE FROM `cron_schedule  
  ` WHERE (status = 'error') AND (job_code in ('indexer_reindex_all_invalid',  
   'indexer_update_all_views', 'indexer_clean_all_changelogs')) AND (created_  
  at < '2021-02-02 08:05:07')
```

The status from where condition, sometimes is `pending`, sometimes is `success`, sometimes, like in the above example is `error` or

```
    SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to   
  get lock; try restarting transaction
```

I found this [POST](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8933) from Magento issues and they said that it is fixed in Magento version `2.3.5`, after they changed their mind and they said, it is fixed with Magento: `2.4.1`  and the last post is saying that it will be fixed in Magento: `2.4.3`. Mostly likely, they will say that it will be fixed in version `2.X.X`. Currently, I am running on Magento `2.3.4`. Any idea what can I do to prevent this deadlock to happen anymore?

Thank you

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problems and I am validating this solution:

```
// in app/etc/env.php
'lock' => [
    'provider' => 'db'
    'config'   => [
       'prefix' => 'new-prefix'
    ]
]
```

Source: https://twitter.com/willemwigman/status/1177162364308860928